# nohup process shown in ps but not in top

Tags: linux, bash, nohup, ps

I ran a python script say `script.py` as follows:

```
nohup python3 script.py &
```

Now, a process ID is given to me, and the following message comes:

```
$  nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

Now I tried to see `top`, which shows `python3` for some time, and then it is not shown anymore. Using the `ps` command eventually showed the process. So, I used the process ID to kill it, (which I thought could overcome hanging). Then again I 
used the `nohup` command. But again the same things happen.

This may be happening because I'm failing to overcome `nohup` hanging. This means that I had run this command earlier, and now I need to re-align the streams of `nohup`. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging))

My question here is, what should I do now? `nohup` is still hanged, and I am not able to run commands in the background. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem created because you used & operator. & gone command to the background and set it as an idle command.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking me to do. Can you give me some commands (with formatting if possible!)?

Comment: use the command without &: For example: 
nohup python3 script.py